# Detect text overflow in JButton

Tags: java, jbutton

I am trying to detect whether the text of a `JButton` fits within the current width, and doesn't overflow like this:

[image: Like this]

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971178/find-out-if-text-of-jlabel-exceeds-label-size) help?

Comment: How about: `if(getPrefferredSize().width > getSize().width)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check it like this:

```
if (myBtn.getPreferredSize().width > myBtn.getSize().width)
```

Comment: Should be `getPreferredSize()`

Comment: @OrangePeel:- Indeed, a typo. Fixed that!