# Determine Whether JLabel Text is Being Cut Off?

Tags: java, swing, text, jframe, jlabel

I have a JLabel, and as the JFrame window expands, the font size automatically changes. The text that is in the JLabel can either be abbreviated or put in full text like so:

[image: Small and Large Window Exmaple]

Because I am using Eclipse's "AbsoluteLayout" for Swing (`frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null)`), JLabels won't automatically resize to the size of the texts and are fixed values. Note that I do change those fixed values as the window changes size. I already have an algorithm for this.

Instead of doing a large calculation determining whether the window is large enough to display the un-abreviated text, I would like to know if there is a way to determine whether my text would appear like this:

[image: Cut off JLabel text]

If I could know that the text would be cut off (due to long text in a small JLabel), I could abbreviate the text, otherwise display it in full.

Is there any way to do what I'm asking while still using the AbsoluteLayout?

**Note:** It is necessary that I use AbsoluteLayout, so don't bother commenting about it even though it is typically regarded as bad practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ideal method to truncate a string with ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597550/ideal-method-to-truncate-a-string-with-ellipsis)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971178/find-out-if-text-of-jlabel-exceeds-label-size

Comment: And avoid `null-layout`, you can even change the Layout Manager in Netbeans, so avoid it. [It's evil](https://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [frowned uppon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing), I bet I would get something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097) if I run your code in my computer, you **don't** want that to happen

Comment: Compare the size of the `JLabel` to the width of the text. There's no way to determine if the text fits whatever space without measuring how much the text takes.

Answer (score 3):

> If I could know that the text would be cut off (due to long text in a small JLabel), I could abbreviate the text, otherwise display it in full.

Compare the width of `getPreferredSize()` and `getSize()`.

Comment: Which basically measures the text in the `JLabel`.