# Fitting text to JTextField using

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField textField` and I have an arbitrary `String string`

I want the text field to display the string's end but cut off what it can't fit and use "..." in place of it. For example, if the string is `"Hello How Are You Doing"` then the text field may look something like

```
...re You Doing
```

Given `textfield` and `string`, how can I do this?

UPDATE: the reason I want to do this is because it's a file chooser so I want to display the end of the file with priority. Example, if the user selects to save at /Users/Name/Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/file.txt then I want to display the end and the rest that can't fit should be replaced with "..."

Here is where it's done:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int response = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String string = file.getAbsolutePath();

    fileTextField.setText(/* here's where the code would go */);
}
```

Comment: *"display the string's end but cut off what it can't fit"*  Why do it opposite to the usual way of trimming the end of the string?  Seems very counter intuitive.

Comment: although ugly and not recommended, you could try re-`pack`ing the container.

Comment: @AndrewThompson See update for a reason if it really matters to you.

Comment: @mre could you provide code for that?

Comment: Why not put the `File` into a single element `JList` with a renderer that shows the file name as the string and full path as the tool-tip?

Comment: @AndrewThompson That seems like overkill to me. I'd like to keep it the way I have it and somehow compute how many letters can fit into the textField

Comment: `JTextField` has auto scrolling capabilities, wouldn't something like a `JLabel` be better??

Comment: See also [*Ideal method to truncate a string with ellipsis*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3597550/230513).

Comment: @trashgod it doesn't need to cut off as to preserve a word

Comment: @MadProgrammer I suppose. That's fine, the code is the same. Just with label.setText() instead

Comment: @CodeGuy Do you care about a fixed `String` length or the available space??

Comment: there must be no_hacky way by using with SwingConstants & ComponentOrientations, dont cut visible text, its crazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you will face is the fact that `String#length` doesn't match pixel width.  You need to take into consideration the current font, the width of the component, the icon, icon spacing, insets, screen DPI.... :P

[image]

```
public class TrimPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TrimPath();
    }

    public TrimPath() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                File path = new File("C:\\Users\\Default\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\GameExplorer");
                TrimmedLabel label = new TrimmedLabel(path.getPath());
                label.setIcon(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(path));

                frame.add(label);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TrimmedLabel extends JLabel {

        private String masterText;

        public TrimmedLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void setText(String text) {
            if (masterText == null ? text != null : !masterText.equals(text)) {
                masterText = text;
                super.setText(text);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getText() {

            String text = getMasterText();

            if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
                int width = getWidth();
                Icon icon = getIcon();
                if (icon != null) {
                    width -= (icon.getIconWidth() + getIconTextGap());
                }
                FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                if (width > 0 && fm != null) {
                    int strWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
                    if (strWidth > width) {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
                        String prefix = "...";
                        while (fm.stringWidth(prefix + sb.toString()) > width) {
                            sb.delete(0, 1);
                        }
                        text = prefix + sb.toString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return text;
        }

        public String getMasterText() {
            return masterText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition `if (width > 0 && fm != null)` should also include a non-null test on `text`: `if (width > 0 && fm != null && text != null)` otherwise you will have a NPE on the next line.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Fair point, I've added in a check for `null` and empty `String`, cheers

Answer (score 5):

> ..it's a file chooser so I want to display the end of the file with priority.

I suggest either this as an alternative, or drop the tool-tip (path) in after the file name.

[image: FileListName]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import java.io.File;

class FileListName {

    final class FileListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        private FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            JLabel l = (JLabel) c;
            File f = (File) value;
            l.setText(f.getName());
            l.setIcon(fsv.getSystemIcon(f));
            l.setToolTipText(f.getAbsolutePath());

            return l;
        }
    }

    public FileListName() {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (jfc.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            File[] f = {jfc.getSelectedFile()};
            JList list = new JList(f);
            list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
            list.setCellRenderer(new FileListCellRenderer());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Provides better icons from the FSV.
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                new FileListName();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Since the icon was only a couple of keystrokes away, I could not resist adding it. :)

Answer (score 0):

can be done by setting your own Document

(this is quick'n'dirty so test lots of times)

```
final int CHAR_DISPLAY_MAX = 10;
final int REPLACE_NUMBER = 3;
final JTextField tf = new JTextField(7);
Document doc = new PlainDocument(){
  public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException{
    if (this.getLength() + str.length() > CHAR_DISPLAY_MAX)
    {
      String oldText = tf.getText();
      String newText = oldText+str;
      tf.setText("..."+newText.substring(newText.length() - (CHAR_DISPLAY_MAX-REPLACE_NUMBER)));
      return;
    }
    super.insertString(offs, str, a);
  }
};
tf.setDocument(doc);
```

Comment: <shudder> no, that's certainly not what you want to do. The document is-a _model_ and as such doesn't (and must not) know about the view state nor change it ...