# How to verify if a string has ellipsis (...)in it through java?

Tags: java, ellipsis

One of my java methods returns a paragraph string. How can i verify if the string has an ellipsis (...) in it?

Comment: Do you mean, for [exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513), "Will the string be _rendered_ with an ellipsis when placed in some GUI component?"

Comment: yes, and as said below, it worked with all. String.contains, String.indexof. I was trying three dots while searching for the ellipsis, but when replaced three dots with actual ellipsis, all below suggestions worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the whacky "ellipsis character" (ASCII 133 `…` three little dots in one character), simply code that character in a string used with the [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

```
s.contains("…") // Not s.contains("...") (ie not "dot dot dot")
```

Copy-paste the ellipsis character from this answer into your code if you have to.

Comment: it worked, you are true, i was searching for three dots. when replaced it with actual ellipsis, it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
myString.contains ("...");
```

It's in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: @Imperta, then you might have a funny "ellipsis" in there or it doesn't contain it. A simple test (1 string, 1 output statement) does conclude that `.contains()` works.

Comment: @Andrew it seems it doesn't work for them, which, unless they have some odd formatting/not an ellipsis, should work (same with your answer, it's basically the same comparison).

Comment: I misread the "thanks" as "good, it now know the string doesn't contain an ellipsis". My bad.

Comment: it worked thanks, @Bohemian was right, i was using three dots instead of ellipsis while searching for it.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if ( myString.indexOf("...") != -1 )
{
    // string contains ellipsis
}
```