# How to customize JLabel abbreviate text

Tags: java, jlabel

when the text in the label is too long JLabel abbreviate it and add ... to the end. How I can customized this text ?

I have method which abbreviate to long text and now I dont know how I can pass it to JLabel:

```
public static String abbreviateMiddle(String str, String middle, int length, int lengthSuffix) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(str) || StringUtils.isEmpty(middle)) {
        return str;
    }

    if (length >= str.length() || length < (middle.length() + 2) || lengthSuffix > length
            || str.length() < lengthSuffix || length - middle.length() < lengthSuffix) {
        return str;
    }

    int targetSting = length - middle.length();
    int endOffset = str.length() - lengthSuffix;
    int startOffset = targetSting - lengthSuffix;

    StrBuilder builder = new StrBuilder(length);
    builder.append(str.substring(0, startOffset));
    builder.append(middle);
    builder.append(str.substring(endOffset));

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513), the label's UI delegate adds the ellipsis as required in `layoutCL()`. REsize the frame to se the effect. You can intercept the result to return whatever `String` you prefer.