# Swing JLabel check if text got clipped

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

when a JLabel's text does not completely fit into the label, it will be cut off and "..." is appended.

Can I somehow check if this has happened? 
Like: `JLabel.isTextClipped()`?

Comment: I don't think there is such a method. But if you want to avoid _"clipping"_ use `.pack()` instead of setting sizes explicity

Comment: @peeskillet: It _is_ possible, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513), but it should't matter in a resizable container.