# difference between Jlabel and noneditable JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Forgive me if this question is trivial. I am not a GUI expert. However, i need to create a Swing control in which the text will only be inserted programmatically based on some calculation (user input never allowed).  Are there any preferences here to use JLabel vs. noneditable JTextField?  I understand that both will work, but just curious if it is better to use one or another in such circumstances.

Comment: A `JTextField` can be focused, the user can select the text and copy it if need be.  If there *ever* would be a need for the user to transfer that information into another app. or record it etc., I would choose the text area/field.  Of course, if you implement D'n'D for the data item, the need for copy/paste is diminished.

Comment: I apologize, JTextField

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for answering my question. Yes, C&P is good functionality, so JTextField it is.    And, btw, what is D'n'D?

Comment: The JLabel can handle ImageIcons *much* better than a JTextField.

Comment: JLabel supports some basic html tags, which can be handy to add some styling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike a `JLabel`, a non-editable `JTextField` can still be scrolled horizontally to see text that would be replaced by ellipses in a `JLabel`. More on the latter can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513).

Answer (score 6):

[image: That's how they look and behave]

The difference is how they look and behave. Also you can cut(&paste) from JTextField.

Comment: See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)  (I'm thinking specifically **'alt** + Print Screen' here to crop the size to the active window.)